# Jenkins Powershell script to wait till application running on tomcat finishes starting up

Tags: powershell, jenkins, tomcat

We have Pega application running on Tomcat and I want to remotely stop/start tomcat via jenkins to restart Pega application. The problem is I need to create a script that should wait until pega starting up in a particular server, so that once started up I can proceed to next adjacent server to do the same.

I need to build a script that exit once "https://localhost:8080/prweb"starts running. I have tried, wait until "curl -O https://localhost:8080/prweb" finishes execution but it didn't work.

please assist.

Comment: The following powershell command will make your job to wait. It is not tested, but also you may need to tweak the command. ```while ((Test-NetConnection -computername localhost -Port 80 ).pingSucceeded -eq $False ) { Start-Sleep -seconds 180 }```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I had to make one change, instead of pingSucceeded i used TcpTestSucceeded to make it work.
`while ((Test-NetConnection -computername localhost -Port 8080 ).TcpTestSucceeded -eq $False ) 
{ 
 Start-Sleep -seconds 2
}`

Comment: Glad to help. If you like my answer, Please mark it as an answer or close it from your end. This 'while' method I used to wait till a VM creates a NIC and IP is assigned, but with a different command :)